# Cannot get instance value in Django rest update view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 3.0 djangorestframework==3.11.0. I have created a task update view and passing the pk to url. The problem is - Although I have set the serializer instance to the model object I want to update. The serializer instance is not showing up.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Task

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apiOverview, name='api-overview'),
    path('task-list/', views.taskList, name='task-list'),
    path('task-detail/<str:pk>/', views.taskDetail, name='task-detail'),
    path('task-create/', views.taskCreate, name='task-create'),
   path('task-update/<str:pk>/', views.taskUpdate, name='task-update'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Task
from .serializers import TaskSerializer

@api_view(['POST'])
def taskUpdate(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TaskSerializer(instance=task, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

expected behavior on url http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/4/

[image: expected view on url http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/4/]

actual behaviour on http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/4/

[image: actual behaviour on http://localhost:8000/api/task-update/4/]

as you can see the content field is empty but I want the already associated json to be shown there with pk = 4.

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel and use Class Based View approach and inherit ListView, CreateView and UpdateView. Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: This style of endpoints is a bit hard. Use classes instead they are much easier to code. I think it is better practice to use endpoints like this for something like small ajax requests.

In normal endpoints u do not have to repeat logic with data serialization.

Comment: @MikołajRutecki writes good things. And even better to use mixins like "mixins.CreateModelMixin" with "viewsets.GenericViewSet" or "viewsets.ModelViewSet"